# Installing and Using developement tools in Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, apt-get, package-managers

I'm completey new to Solaris, coming from a Linux background. I would like to know how can I install developement tools such as gcc, g++ etc... on Solaris and also any other program. Is there any equivalent of apt-get, sudo etc... Secondly, what is the advantage of OpenSolaris over Oracle Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some web searching turns up [BlastWave](http://www.blastwave.org/). It's payware. The [`pkgin`](http://pkgin.net/)/`pkgsrc` package manager, originally from NetBSD, has also been ported to Solaris.

If you're not tied to a specific Solaris version, then you might be interested in the OpenSolaris distro [Nexenta](http://www.nexenta.org/), which has a GNU/Linux userland ported over from Ubuntu, including the Debian package manager and `apt-get`. (There's your Solaris vs. OpenSolaris difference; also, I'm not sure if OpenSolaris runs on SPARC hardware.)

Comment: I see, then it would be wise for me to switch to OpenSolaris :)!

Comment: Its fine, I don't need to run OpenSolaris on SPARC, just on x86.

Comment: I have installed Nexenta Solaris with Vmware, but it boots to command line. Do you know a way of how to start the gui mode?

Comment: Try `startx` or `telinit 5`. Or maybe you have to `apt-get` the X server and GNOME first :)

Comment: The OpenSolaris distro is no longer made, Oracle replaced it with the [Solaris 11 Express distro](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/), which is free for development and testing, but requires a support contract to go into production.   The community has forked off several alternative distros based on the OpenSolaris sources, including [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/) and [Nexenta Core](http://www.nexenta.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In modern days, i.e. Solaris 11 and beyond, you wouldn't have to go to third parties to get this. The equivalent of `apt-get` in Solaris is the `pkg` command. This package manager is known as IPS.

For example to get the most typical development tools (your question) simply execute the command below as root or similar user.

```
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/gnu-make \
            pkg://solaris/developer/build/make \
            pkg://solaris/developer/gcc-45 \
            pkg://solaris/system/header \
            pkg://solaris/developer/build/autoconf \
            pkg://solaris/developer/build/automake-110
```

For more information look at [this posting on Unix&Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72883/22123).

Oracle runs its own IPS repo which is what you reference when you prepend package names with `pkg://solaris` as in the example above. There are third-party repos out there as well but I've found Oracle's to be pretty complete for my needs.

Remember that Solaris is really a **server operating system**. In this respect it is second-to-none. You *can* use it as a desktop operating system as well but compared to things like Ubuntu and Windows it is far behind.

Answer (score 0):

#### Package management

*BlastWave* is dead for a long time now.

Please try [OpenCSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCSW) instead. It has package repositories for Solaris 8 onwards, both *x86* and *SPARC*.

Package installation is as easy as `pkgutil -i <package name>`; all dependencies will be resolved automatically.

#### Distribution selection

As for the OS itself, I'd recommend Sun/Oracle versions over *Nexenta* and other forks, as they seem to have a larger user base (so it's easier to get help). Additionally, *ZFS* implementation in the official Solaris is likely to be more stable and feature-rich. The same is true for *dtrace*.

Plus, you get the standard Sun-enhanced CDE desktop.

#### Forks

If you decide to proceed with a fork instead -- the list of distributions based on the *Illumos* kernel is not limited to *Nexenta* alone: see [here](http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Distributions).

For desktops, [OpenIndiana](http://www.openindiana.org/download/), [OpenSXCE](http://opensxce.org/) and [Tribblix](http://www.tribblix.org/install.html) appear to be the best candidacies.